# JNI with static library: unsatisfied link error

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I've built a static library with g++:

`g++-5 main.cpp -fPIC -Wall -std=c++11 -lboost_system ......`

Now I want to call its methods via JNI:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.load("/Users/XXX/example/libjnidb4java.a");
    JNIDB db = new JNIDB();
    db.createTable("Name", "Dir");
  }
```

Turns out there's a `UnsatisfiedLinkError` Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /Users/XXX/example/libjnidb4java.a: dlopen(/Users/XXX/example/libjnidb4java.a, 1): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Users/XXX/example/libjnidb4java.a: unknown file type, first eight bytes: 0x21 0x3C 0x61 0x72 0x63 0x68 0x3E 0x0A
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1937)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1822)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
```

### NOTE

I tried with dynamic library, it works fine, but in my case, I need it to be static library. I create this static library via  `ar -r libjnidb4java.a a.out`.

And I found Java 8 has already supports statically linked library [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#JNJI_OnLoad). Like the docs say, I created a method :

`jint JNI_OnLoad_xxxdb4java(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
  return JNI_VERSION_1_8;
}`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood something here, but ... you can only load a dynamic library from Java (under linux, this should be an `.so` file)

Comment: Was it really too hard to use a title that actually reflects the problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot dynamically load a static library.  You can only dynamically load a shared library.

The JNI docs you refer to talk about using JNI with static libraries, but that assumes that you've statically linked a library into the JVM.  So if you really *must* use a static library then you're going to have to rebuild your own JVM which sounds like an unenviable experience.

It's not clear to me why there's a difference for you between using a static library and a shared library (you are still trying to dynamically load it, after all, which screams dynamic library to me) but I would try to overcome that limitation first.

If you want to create a single installable unit for your users, then what you want is to create a single shared library of your own.  Your library should then statically link *its* dependencies so that they are included in your library.  You can then use `loadLibrary` on that single unit without worrying about dependencies being installed.

Comment: Thank you, My library `libjnidb4java` depends on some other libraries that are not widely used. So I thought use a static library is better for user experience(They do not need to download an install those dependencies before use `libjnidb4java`)

Comment: @MrROY You can link them statically into your dynamic library. There is no such thing as 'JNI wih a static library' unless you statically link it into the JVM. And certainly no such thing as loading a static library dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  That makes a lot of sense and what @EJP said is right on.  :)